# Android app - http won't work

Tags: android, http

My manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.biscani.alpha"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my MainActivity:

```
    package net.biscani.alpha;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView list = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.netResult);

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                list.setText(reader.readLine());
                webs.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Error in code "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my layout main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.biscani.alpha.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/netResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't display the text from the website I requested in http post, it just appears blank on the screen. Also, how can I parse data from site that has images and other links along with data, like blog articles and such?

**07-09 19:00:59.464: E/log_tag(20792): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show us some code that is actually trying to display the text. Also, the code that is performing the HttpRequest. Also, what website are you trying to get the text from?

Comment: @Georgi Angelov Sorry, misplaced links, edited my post with new link (the main activity). Here's the link of the website I'm trying to get text from: http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php

Comment: gotcha. This is better. can you Log the ouput from this reader.readLine(), instead of directly assigning it to the textview? Store it in a string and then Log it and assign it to the textview. Could you also try removing the buffer size?

Comment: please add your manifest & relevant code as part of your question.  Not only may some people not want to visit your website, but also when you take down the relevant links and they do not work any more this question will be completely useless to future readers.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Could you explain me a bit more? I understood half of what you've said. I'm really confused, this is one of mine first programs, and none of the tutorials helped. Thanks.

Comment: @core_m, String input = reader.readLine();
Log.i("Logging line from reader.readLine()", input);
list.setText(input);
This way you will get a chance to see if you are actually getting anything from the request. Look at your logs in whatever IDE you are using.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov 07-09 19:00:59.464: E/log_tag(20792): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: use `AsyncTask` for sending http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a network operation in onCreate(), which runs on the UI Thread.

You should run your code in a new Thread, then it will work.

Look at the classes: Thread, Runnable, Handler, AsyncTask, AsyncTaskLoader

See this link for information on the UI Thread and how it shouldn't be 'blocked', also it will demonstrate running code in a separate thread using AsyncTask

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding

Comment: I just got more confused. Could you explain me a bit more? haha

Comment: if you learn about each of those things I said you will be able to do it with ease, theres too much to type here but essentially when you do a Http request on the main thread Android doesnt like it because it makes the UI 'blocked'. So you must create a new Thread to run your code in, follow the classes I listed above it will become more clear.

Comment: The link in my answer explains about the UI Thread and how to use AsyncTask

Comment: Every tutorial I try, it won't work. Copied all from this guys video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3CwlckiLTU, and it seemed to work for him and the others that commented. I really can't understand it, thanks anyway.I was trying to retrieve something like blog articles rather than this, but even this won't work for me hah.

Answer (score 0):

Use your http requests (non UI thread) inside the `AsyncTask` class and get the result in `onpostExecute()`(UI thread)